# how can I align images to top of the row?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the images to the top of the row in this table:

```
<table class="customers">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th  class="first">
            How can I get the images aligned to the top of the row?
        </th>
        <th class="second"></th>
        <th class="third"></th>
        <th class="fourth ng-binding">Mary</th>
        <th ng-class="persons.length>1 ? 'fifth' : (persons.length<2 ? 'fifth_single' : '') " class="ng-binding fifth">

        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-class="'odd'" class="odd border_bottom">
        <td>
            <table class="docInfo">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" ng-click="showTextArea(1)"
                        class="ng-hide"><img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-business/076004-3d-transparent-glass-icon-business-document4.png" alt="docimage"></td>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-binding ng-hide">Mary</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-hide"><span><p
                            class="ng-binding">Mar
                        4, 2015 2:42:25 PM</p></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="docInfo">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" ng-click="showTextArea(1)"
                        class="ng-hide"><img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-business/076004-3d-transparent-glass-icon-business-document4.png" alt="docimage"></td>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-binding ng-hide">Mary</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-hide"><span><p
                            class="ng-binding">Mar
                        4, 2015 2:42:25 PM</p></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-class="'odd'" class="odd borderbottom">
        <td>
            <table class="docInfo">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" ng-click="showTextArea(1)"
                        class="ng-hide"><img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-business/076004-3d-transparent-glass-icon-business-document4.png" alt="docimage"></td>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-binding ng-hide">Mary</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-hide"><span><p
                            class="ng-binding">Mar
                        4, 2015 2:42:25 PM</p></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="docInfo">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" ng-click="showTextArea(1)"
                        class="ng-hide"><img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-business/076004-3d-transparent-glass-icon-business-document4.png" alt="docimage"></td>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-binding ng-hide">Mary</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-show="showDocInfo(1,strategy.statuses[0].reason)" class="ng-hide"><span><p
                            class="ng-binding">Mar
                        4, 2015 2:42:25 PM</p></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-class="'even'" class="even">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-class="'odd'" class="odd">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-class="'even'" class="even">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

At the moment the images are sort of in the middle of each row. How can I get them aligned to the top of the row? I tried to set the verticalalign property but did not fix it.

Here is the stylesheet:

```
.customers
{
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: in 2px;
    float: left;
}

img
{
    height:30px;}

.customers tr.border_bottom > td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

.customers td {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.customers .first {
    width: 40%;
}

.customers .first_single {
    width: 39%;
}

.customers .second {
    width: 20%;
}

.customers .third {
    width: 20%;
}
.customers .fourth {
    width: 20%;
}
.customers .fifth{
    width: 20%;
}

.customers .fifth_single{
    width: 1%;
}

tr.odd>td,tr.even>td{
    width:100%;
}

.docInfo {
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: left;
}

.docInfo td {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    line-height: 0.2;
    font-size: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.first {
    width: 40%;
}

.second {
    width: 60%
}

img {
    background: transparent;
    height: 25px;
}

}
```

Also created a plunkr url:http://plnkr.co/edit/CssSPt?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the

line-height: 0.2;

style that is applied to the .docInfo td 
It is not a large enough line-height for the text and so is causing mis-alignment of your table.

Take this style off and the alignment of the image moves to the top.

If you need this line-height for your text, apply it to the paragraph instead of the table cell.